# How to Copy and paste to another worksheet if value match - Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I need to copy and paste values from sheet1 Columns(A:B) to sheet2 Columns(A:B), if Sheet1 Column F="NUMBERS"

```
Input

A 1 NUMBERS
B 2 TEXT
C 3 NUMBERS
D 4 TEXT
E 5 NUMBERS AND TEXT

OUTPUT
A 1
C 3
```

Currently i use AutoFilter and copy, paste method it sometime gives Error(Because very long Macro).

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.save
Range("A1:J1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$J").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Numbers"
 Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.Copy

 Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

So I need find value and copy paste method (loop based).

Comment: You mean to say copy rows have NUMBER as caption is adjacent cell?

Comment: yeah correct, if the ColF have " Number" word then copy the ColA & B to Next sheet

Comment: Check my post the code will help U to work through loop.

Comment: i dont know why negative votes

Comment: That must be one humongous macro. You could shorten your macro considerably by removing all of those unnecessary `.Select`, `.Selection` as well as references to `ActiveSheet`, `Activate`, and probably other stuff.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld as a beginner i know macro recording and one or two functions. so thats i posted here.

Comment: To get an error because of *very long macro* means you have a huge macro.  Especially as a beginner, you should record small segments of your project, and then make sure you understand what you have done before going on to the next.  With regard to using `Select`, read through the thread on [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).  In addition to shortening your code, it will help you make it more robust and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can use this Macro to Copy entire Row to another Sheet has `Number` as value in `Column F`.*

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRowWithSpecificText()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)
      For Each Cell In .Range("F1:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = "Numbers" Then

            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(Cell.Row)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With
End Sub
```

---

**Edited 1:**

-*If you don't like the Macro to produce blank rows, if any in `Sheet 1` among Rows to be copied, then use this code.*

```
    Sub CopyRowsWithNUMBER()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet


    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    j = 1     
    For Each c In Source.Range("F1:F20")   
        If c = "Numbers" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
    End Sub
```

---

**Edited 2:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCheck As Range
    Dim CheckCell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set rngCheck = Intersect(Me.Columns("F"), Target)

    If Not rngCheck Is Nothing Then

        For Each CheckCell In rngCheck.Cells
            If CheckCell.Value = "Numbers" Then
                With Sheets("sheet2")
                    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Me.Cells(CheckCell.Row, "A").Copy Destination:=.Cells(lRow, "A")
                    Me.Cells(CheckCell.Row, "B").Copy Destination:=.Cells(lRow, "B")

                End With
            End If
        Next CheckCell
    End If

End Sub
```

---

**How it works:**

- **C**opy & **P**aste this code in `Sheet 1` as standard module.
- As soon you enter `Numbers` in any cells of `Column F`, this code will copy data from the `Column A & B` only for the specific Row/Rows to `Sheet 2`.
- Destination Column(s) should different than Source.

**N.B.**

- *Sheet Name, Column (`F`) has specific text, and the specific text, `Number` are adjustable.*
- Save the Workbook as Macro Enabled (`.Xlsm`).

Comment: Isn't this going to produce blank rows on the destination worksheet?

Comment: @Jeeped,, this picks only rows has value `Number` in col F.

Comment: But if *Number* [sic] only appears in rows 1, 3 & 5 then the destination worksheet will have the results on its own 1, 3 & 5.

Comment: Sorry No output , no error comes in this code (something wrong). I don't know why

Comment: @baskar,, check the value Number may be mismatched,  otherwise it's working,,, nothing extraordinary to do!!

Comment: @RajeshS, Its working after change Sheets(1) > Sheets("Sheet1"). As you say its copy all column. Anyway to copy ColA & B only ,Also Blanks comes if the row not with value

Comment: @baskar,,, it doesn't matters whether is Sheet(1) or Sheets("Sheet1") works for both and if U need to copy few columns only [edit] the post & mention this in question!!

Comment: @RajeshS, Already mentioned in first line and my old macro code ColA &B only need to copy. I have one issue in this code if the value not match its make row as blank in output(here 2nd row blank,row 1 and 3 copied).  how to rectify this

Comment: Hi @baskar,, now check my recent post `Edited 2`,, this code copies data only from Column A and B into destination Sheet. I'm sure this what you were looking for !

Comment: Private Sub >  not listed in Macro Run window, Also i use call function not use. How to run this kindly guide me

Comment: @RajeshS, i search on internet for run these sub macro by call/run.application based method. But i dont know exactly how to trigger the macro code. Because my sheet1 Automatically filled by another macro. when i use this code i will add required place or use call function . because of private sub macro, i not able to use this last mentioned code. Sorry for the repeated questions... if you free kindly guide me. As you said last point:  copy paste in sheet1 standard module is already tried but not works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106669/discussion-between-baskar-and-rajesh-s).

Comment: @RajeshS I use <Edited1: Answer> then i delete Other Columns .

Also I am not able to use last Private Sub Macro. Because its need to trigger by manual Dropdown selection (Also i am not able to fully understand the usage).